# How to improve the fill rate when using the `Flatlist` component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In the RN doc `Flatlist` unit.There is a description:

> In order to constrain memory and enable smooth scrolling, content is rendered asynchronously offscreen. This means it's possible to scroll faster than the fill rate and momentarily see blank content. This is a tradeoff that can be adjusted to suit the needs of each application, and we are working on improving it behind the scenes.

I face the issue, sometimes the blank content show. 
How to improve the fill rate　when using the `Flatlist` component?

Comment: Did you get any solutions?

Comment: @Balasubramanian I don't have any solutions yet.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you solved this problem but I wrote [this article](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips) about performance with FlatLists, you should take a look!

In your question you ask about improving the 'fill rate'. Strictly speaking, to improve your fill rate there are two props you should tweak: `updateCellsBatchingPeriod` and `maxToRenderPerBatch`.

`updateCellsBatchingPeriod` is a interval measured in milliseconds which defaults to 50.

`maxToRenderPerBatch` is the number of items rendered on every `updateCellsBatchingPeriod` iteration. Default is 10.

Thing is, you can set a lower `maxToRenderPerBatch` and a lower `updateCellsBatchingPeriod` to have less items rendering on a little interval or set a bigger `maxToRenderPerBatch` and a bigger `updateCellsBatchingPeriod` to render more items on a bigger interval. Which works best for you.

But there is no free lunch. Having more operations per second, means you will have less responsiveness to touch events, for example. So I recommend you take a look at my article to learn a little more on how you could enhance your FlatList.

Comment: Your article is wrong about `windowSize`. "You can set the windowSize={number}. The number passed here is a measurement unit where 1 is equivalent to your viewport height." - The correct answer is that the window size is the number of items to render and keep ready to be scrolled in. Has nothing to do with viewport or its size.

Comment: @oldwizard Could you at least do a little research before posting something along the lines of "your article is wrong, period"?

Comment: @oldwizard From [React Native's CODE comments, about windowSize:](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e428093e2d959d415e228b1c0e12ddd569aff89/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L237) Determines the maximum number of items rendered outside of the visible area, **in units of visible lengths**. So if your list fills the screen, then `windowSize={21}` (the default) will render the visible screen area plus up to **10 screens** above and 10 below the viewport.

Comment: Oh that is indeed the case! So if your FlatList is flexed, full screen height, the optimal value for windowSize might very well be 1 (if you are memory constrained fxp). Since the other properties are based on "number of items", not height, it would make sense if windowSize was also based on number of items imho. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

use `maxToRenderPerBatch={10}` 10 is the default. Take a look at [Virtualized List](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L137)

Comment: @FilipeMerker it's ten https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7d741d1119532213e2c30707320351fb56c63953/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L439

Answer (score 0):

this may help by using these props to adjust :

```
maxToRenderPerBatch={1000}
windowSize={60}           
updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}   
initialNumToRender={50}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate what each props does?

Comment: @Balasubramanian please refer to this link  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#initialnumtorender

Comment: 1000 maxRenderPerBatch is insane, depending on the complexity of the list. Also you have set the updateCellsBatchingPeriod to the default value, what is the point?

Comment: I want to point out that adjust these props can solve the fill rate (blank rendering when fast scrolling) problem, the values need to be adjusted case by case. Recently, I found that don't set maxToRenderPerBatch and set windowSize={Dimensions.get('window').height*2} can solve this fill rate problem.

Answer (score 0):

fill rate can be improved when using the `Flatlist` component:

- try to use less conditions in render items
- use maxToRenderPerBatch, updateCellsBatchingPeriod and removeClippedSubviews={true}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).